# supertiled2unity isometric tilemap import looks weird in game view

Tags: unity, tiled2unity

I am using Tiled to streamline the process of creating maps for my game. I am using SuperTiled2Unity to import the Tiled tilemaps into unity. That worked successfully. But when I added an imported tilemap into my scene, it looks all distorted in game view.
[image: scene view vs. game view]

As you can see the game view looks extremely distorted.
**How to reproduce**
Step 1: Create new unity project
Step 2: Install SuperTiled2Unity
Step 3: Turn anti-aliasing off
Step 4: Create a Tiled tileset
Step 5: Create a isometric Tiled tilemap with a 32x16
Step 6: Add the Tiled tilemap into your scene

Comment: Note that your game view is zoomed in 4x. You probably meant to scale up your TileMap itself or crop your camera in smaller to give each tile more pixels, rather than blowing up the small number of pixels to look chunkier.

Comment: @DMGregory I scaled up the tilemap in the scene view and it fixed the problem thanks!

Comment: Be sure to post your solution as an Answer below.